# How can I have a GKE cluster "expire" and delete itself?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

We stand up a lot of clusters for testing/poc/deving and its up to us to remember to delete them

What I would like is a way of setting a ttl on an entire gke cluster and having it get deleted/purged automatically.

I could tag the clusters with a timestamp at creation and have an external process running on a schedule that reaps old clusters, but it'd be great if I didn't have to do that- it might be the only way but maybe there is a gke/k8s feature for this?

Is there a way to have the cluster delete itself without relying on an external service? I suppose it could spawn a cloud function itself- but Im wondering if there is a native gke/k8s feature to do this more elegantly

Answer (score 2):

You can spawn GKE cluster with Alpha features. Such clusters exist for one month maximum and then are auto-deleted. 
Read more: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/alpha-clusters

Comment: well thats not what I want. this is like a goofy way of achieving this. Besides I want to set an arbitrary ttl and use stable (not alpha) versions either

Comment: There is no such thing in Google Cloud. You have to write your own logic to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Try Cloud Scheduler and hook it up with your build server. Cloud Scheduler supports Http , App Engine , Pub/Sub endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a native way to do this, but it doesn't seem unreasonable to use cloud scheduler to every so often trigger a cloud function which looks for appropriately labeled clusters and triggers their deletion via the API.